# javascript selection of particular element

Tags: javascript

i have got two containers

```
<div class="container">
     <button>Remove</button>
     <div class="des">First desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Second desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Tird desscription </div>
</div>
```

now i want to remove the class .des on clicking to remove button but when i click on remove every .des of the page is removed.. i want to remove particular 'container's ' .des .. any solution?

i used querySelectorAll on .des and used for loop which makes every .des removed

Comment: In the button's `onclick` handler, you can do `this.closest(".container").querySelector(".des").remove()`

Comment: `this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('des')`...!

Comment: @Jai OP wants to remove the `<div>` entirely, as far as I can tell. But doesn't really matter anyway, the main issue is to get from button to `.des` and both show how to get there. And should the button ever move elsewhere in the container, mine will still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of the button pass the element and using parentElement get the container element and selecting the .des element by querySelector . Using removeAttribute remove the class attribute

```js
function a(ele)
{
ele.parentElement.querySelector('.des').removeAttribute('class')
}
```

```css
.des
{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <button onclick='a(this)'>Remove</button>
     <div class="des">First desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button onclick='a(this)'>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Second desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container" >
    <button onclick='a(this)'>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Tird desscription </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript, you can do this by acting on the `event.target` property. In this case: `parent.querySelector('.des')`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement;
    parent.querySelector('.des').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <button>Remove</button>
     <div class="des">First desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Second desscription </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button>Remove</button>
    <div class="des">Tird desscription </div>
</div>
```